# Precision for function

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have a notebook where I have to work with high precision (say, 100). I have tried several methods to define it for the entire notebook, including

```
$MinPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision
```

but when I define a function, say:

```
f[x_] := x^3;
```

that function does not have the required precision. Moreover, when I try to NIntegrate that function, I get a "The precision of the argument function ... is less than WorkinPrecision".

What should I do to solve this?

Edit:
Here is my actual function which I am trying to numerically integrate over the sphere:

```
d[n_, H_, q_] := 
 Table[Sum[
   Sum[(n[[i]] - q[[i]]) (H[[j, k]] n[[j]] n[[k]])/(2 (1 - q.n)), {k, 
      1, 3}] - 1/2 H[[i, j]] n[[j]], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

The numerical integration I use is

```
NIntegrate[
 Sin[θ] (d[n, H, q].{1.0, 0.0, 
     0.0}) (d[m, H, q].{Cos[α], 
     0.0, -Sin[α]}), {θ, 0.0, π}, {ϕ, 
  0.0, 2.0 π}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Here, `n` and `q` are vectors:

```
n = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
m = {Sin[α], 0.0, Cos[α]};
q = {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
```

and `R` is a matrix

```
R = Simplify[
   Inverse[RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 1, 0}]].Inverse[
     RotationMatrix[ϕ, {0, 0, 1}]]];

H = Transpose[R].( {
     {1.0, 1.0, 0.0},
     {1.0, -1.0, 0.0},
     {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    } ).R;
```

The integration is over `θ` and `ϕ`.

Comment: You haver not shown the `NIntegrate` expression that you are used. We cannot reproduce your problem without all of the relevant code.

Comment: I have now included it.

Comment: What happens when you replace all your machine `0.0`, `1.0` etc. with exact `0`, `1`, etc.?

Comment: As @JohnDoty said, machine precision numbers (e.g., 0.0, 1.0, 2.0) "contaminate" the precision of everything they touch. Either use exact numbers, high precision arbitrary precision numbers,  or `Rationalize` the numbers. You have not defined `\[Alpha]` so the numeric integration cannot be performed.

Comment: I actually changed them from 1 to 1.0 etc. in an attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: The numerical integration is defined for any value of \[Alpha] from 0 to Pi.

Answer (score 3):

The precision of an exact function like `f[x_] := x^3` depends on its input:

```
Precision[f[2]]
(* \[Infinity] *)
```

Control the input precision (3 digits here) to get a controlled precision result:

```
Precision[f[2`3]]
(* 2.52288 *)
```

A number with a decimal point and no precision specification is a "machine" number. Machine numbers are special: unless you explicitly prevent them, they infect calculations with their precision and disable precision tracking. Here, the machine constant `1.5` forces calculations to be in machine precision:

```
g[x_] := x^3 + 1.5
Precision[g[2`3]]
(* MachinePrecision *)
```

If you want a function to yield controlled precision output, avoid machine constants in its definition. It's best to use exact constants: `1/3`, `Pi`, `Sqrt[2]`, `Root[1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this might help

```
α = Pi/4;
n = {0, 0, 1};
m = {Sin[α], 0, Cos[α]};
q = {Sin[θ] Cos[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[θ]};
R = Inverse[RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 1, 0}]].Inverse[RotationMatrix[φ, {0, 0, 1}]];
H = Transpose[R].({{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}).R;
d[n_, H_, q_] := Table[Sum[Sum[
  (n[[i]] - q[[i]]) (H[[j, k]] n[[j]] n[[k]])/(2 (1 - q.n)), {k, 1, 3}] -
  1/2 H[[i, j]] n[[j]], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 3}];
```

When I have a reluctant definite integral the first thing I try is `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` on the integrand and look for denominators or oscillations or infinities. That `FullSimplify` gives a result which is a tiny fraction of your original unsimplified expression and is half the size of just `Simplify`. For particularly difficult cases you can let `FullSimplify` know the domain of φ and θ and see if that helps it even further reduce the size of the expression.

```
FullSimplify[Sin[θ] (d[n, H, q].{1, 0, 0}) (d[m, H, q].{Cos[α], 0, -Sin[α]})]
```

which shows me

```
-((Sin[θ]^2 (Cos[φ] + Sin[φ]) ((-8 Cos[θ] + Sqrt[2] (3 + Cos[2 θ])) Cos[2 φ] +
8 Cos[φ] Sin[θ] - 6 Sqrt[2] Sin[θ]^2 - 4 Sin[2 θ] Sin[φ] + 
2 (3 - 2 Sqrt[2] Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ]) Sin[2 φ]))/(32 (-Sqrt[2] + Cos[θ] + Cos[φ] Sin[θ])))
```

that yes you do have denominators which might go to zero.

The next thing I do is look at a `Plot`

```
Plot3D[FullSimplify[
  Sin[θ] (d[n, H, q].{1, 0, 0}) (d[m, H, q].{Cos[α], 0, -Sin[α]})],
  {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

This doesn't look bad, it doesn't appear to wildly oscillate near any point, doesn't appear to go to infinity, doesn't have any gaping holes were it isn't defined. But `Plot` can sometimes lie to me so I look for zero denominators.

And `Reduce` tells me that the denominator does go to zero

```
N[Reduce[{32 (-Sqrt[2] + Cos[θ] + Cos[φ] Sin[θ]) ==
  0, 0 <= θ <= Pi, 0 <= φ <= 2 Pi}, {θ, θ}] // Simplify]
```

which happens when

```
θ == 0.785398 && (φ == 0. || φ == 6.28319)
```

And yes,  θ == Pi/4 with φ == 0 or φ == 2Pi give an integrand of 1/0 and those two points appear to have been missed by `Plot`. You might want to explore the behavior near those two points and see what you get.

So those may be the sticking points that `NIntegrate` is complaining about.

But I try anyway

```
NIntegrate[FullSimplify[
  Sin[θ] (d[n, H, q].{1, 0, 0}) (d[m, H, q].{Cos[α], 0, -Sin[α]})],
  {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

And the default method used by `NIntegrate` complains about it is having problems getting the result to converge, but it does finally give about 20 digits of precision.

You can try giving `NIntegrate` some Method options to see if you can get it to stop complaining or give a better result, but this doesn't seem to be necessary.

Now you just need to decide whether that result really is correct or not.

Comment: It gives the correct answer up to 10^-12, where it diverges from the true value.

Comment: You should probably set `WorkingPrecision` to twice the precision of the desired result. See also `PrecisionGoal`.

Answer (score 0):

Constants must be defined exactly, should be so

```
    n = {0, 0, 1};
m = {Sin[α], 0, Cos[α]};
q = {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
   Cos[θ]};
R = Simplify[
   Inverse[RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 1, 0}]].Inverse[
     RotationMatrix[ϕ, {0, 0, 1}]]];
H = Transpose[R].({{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}).R;
t = Table[
   Sum[Sum[(n[[i]] - 
         q[[i]]) (H[[j, k]] n[[j]] n[[k]])/(2 (1 - q.n)), {k, 1, 
       3}] - 1/2 H[[i, j]] n[[j]], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 3}];
t1 = Table[
   Sum[Sum[(m[[i]] - 
         q[[i]]) (H[[j, k]] m[[j]] m[[k]])/(2 (1 - q.m)), {k, 1, 
       3}] - 1/2 H[[i, j]] m[[j]], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 3}];
int = Sin[θ] (t.{1, 0, 0}) (t1.{Cos[α], 
      0, -Sin[α]});
NIntegrate[
 int /. α -> Pi/4, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
0.55395347102611116853
```

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that my function is more complicated than that, and involves constants, etc. When I do NIntegrate with WorkingPrecision->100, all I get is "The precision of the argument function [...] is less than WorkingPrecision (100.`)."

Comment: Can you show how you numerically define constants?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the function I am trying to integrate numerically.

Comment: How the matrix H is defined? H=R?

Comment: I have defined it better now, thanks.

Comment: Constants must be defined exactly, should be so `H = Transpose[R].({{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}).R;`

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't solve the Precision issues.

Comment: I edited my answer in accordance with the new data

Comment: Thank you, I get the message "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small."

Comment: Do not pay attention to this message. What was the result?